# Portioning taxable state refunds when living and working in different states

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, income-tax-refund, illinois

I live in Indiana, but work in Illinois -- some of my job contracts are on-site in Illinois, and others are remote work. Last year, I received a taxable state refund from Illinois.

In my Schedule NR for Illinois, I am asked to provide the portion of each type of income that is assignable to Illinois. For income from jobs worked on site, this is easy: I assign all of that income to Illinois. For income from jobs where I worked remotely from Indiana, this is also easy: all income is assigned to Indiana (unless I've been terribly misled on this point). Interest income from savings accounts, too, is assigned to my state of residency. However, I am not certain how to split up 2017 Illinois state refunds.

I am inclined to believe that because the money contained in these refunds was originally earned on-site in Illinois, that this money still 'counts' as being earned in Illinois -- as such, it would all be assigned to Illinois. However, it was paid out while I was living in Indiana -- so would this be more similar to interest income or remote work income, and assigned to my state of residency?

In short: are tax refunds from state X assigned to state X when dividing income among several states, or should they be assigned to state Y of residency? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Surely your Illinois state tax isn’t deductible on your Illinois state tax return, hence your Illinois state tax refund isn’t taxable in Illinois. Unless Illinois tax rules are very strange.

Comment: A good point, prl. I've modified the post to reflect the concern a bit better -- it's more about what state to assign the refund to as income. If I assign it to Illinois, then perhaps being 'taxed' at Illinois rates means paying nothing at all, because it's deductible.  However, if I assign it to Indiana, perhaps that is no longer true? My confusion may be amplified by the fact that these state returns do suffer a federal tax, as I itemized my deductions last year.